# How can I change the default directory "pip install" installs to in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, pip, pycharm

When I want to install the openpyxl package via `pip install openpyxl` it automatically installs it to

C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages

When I import it in line 1 of my code with `import openpyxl` I get an error that openpyxl isn't installed and thus cannot be imported. I found the solution is to copy the packages to:

C:\Users\MyName\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\Lib\site-packages

After that I don't get the error anymore and can work with my downloaded packages and import them. However, when I install another programm with `pip install` it goes to the wrong directory again and I have to manually move it again. How can I change it, so that pip installs to the correct directory by default? Is there a way to use packages installed in the directory pip currently installs them in?

I hope that's all the info you need, I tried to explain it to the best of my abilities. If anything is missing please let me know. I'm using PyCharm on Windows 10 and just started with coding a few days ago, so please make your answer a bit beginner-friendly.

Comment: Just run `pip install` from the activated virtualenv. What tools are you using to create and manage your virtualenvs?

Comment: This was exactly the solution to my problem, it was just as simple as that.

I'm currently following CodeWithMosh's Python course and he installs the package and is able to run it immediately, which I wasn't. I then looked for ways to resolve my issue and found the way I described in my question. Two videos later he brought up the topic of virtualenvs and it worked then.

Comment: "I found the solution is to copy the packages to:

C:\Users\MyName\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\venv\Lib\site-package" Never do this in the future. Do not `pip install` a package and then move it to some other dir because the package cannot be imported, There is always something else going wrong then. You can mess things up doing that.